# PUT and POST requests in Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-model, backbone-forms

I have another question related to the PUT and POST requests. So, here I have a form which has the fields like : "name" and "link".

On submit of that form, I am not able to post that form to the server on doing this.model.save();

Also, how do I understand when will the model be invoking a POST and when will it invoke a PUT request? Since I dont have any "id" attribute from my api response so I dont have any id for my model too.

So how do I pass my form field value on click of the "Submit" button as a POST request?

Also, Is there a way I can invoke the request: For eg: If i hit on the "Update" button of my form, I will call a function from my model

```
updateModel:function(options){
this.update("update","/messages",[options])
}
```

or a get request can be read like this

```
getModel:function(options){
this.update("read","/messages",[options])
}
```

Comment: "On submit of that form, I am not able to post that form to the server on doing this.model.save();" **Why are you unable to do this?**

Comment: I am not sure... it doesn't invoke the POST or PUT method

Comment: Nothing is going to do that automatically. You need an event handler like in my answer to call `save`.

Comment: ok.. so I tried your way and here is what I get as response OPTIONS /abc/messages..     What is this OPTIONS? Why is it not going as POST?

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a fiddle of it or something I will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The save method will determine whether to POST or PUT based on the return value of `isNew()`. This method generally just checks for an `id` being populated. You can override it to use some other indicator.

You pass form field values on submit directly into your save method. Something like this:

```
//In your view
events : {"submit" : "onSubmit"},
onSubmit : function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.model.save({name: this.$("#name").val()}, {
    success : function (newModel) { /* Do something here. */ }
  });
}
```

Another alternative is to use a library like `Backbone.Modelbinder` to handle the syncing between DOM and model for you.

You shouldn't need to define those new methods on your model. You should instead define a proper `url` method on the model or corresponding controller. Then you can just use the normal `fetch` and `save` methods to handle your get/updates.